# Web API EF Core exceptions being swallowed?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I have a basic OData Web Api in ASPNetCore, the get method for OData queries is:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable Get() => _db.AllThings;
```

But if any SQL exception is experience during this call, it doesn't appear to be caught, thrown, logged anywhere.

E.g. if I force the query to execute:

```
var q = _db.AllPOs.Take(1);
first = q.First();
```

Then the following exception is thrown:

```
An exception occurred while reading a database value for property 
'AllThing.Number'. The expected type was 'System.Int32' but the actual value 
was of type 'System.String'.
Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
```

So why isn't this thrown when deferring the execution by returning IQueryable?

Answer (score 3):

Note that this isn't specific to `IQueryable`, but to any `IEnumerable` where the results haven't been realized yet.

The actual query is performed when the object is enumerated, which is done by ASP.NET when it's constructing the response - outside of your code, which is why you don't see an exception in your `Get()` method.

The only way to see the exception is to debug the .NET Core code, which you can do with the instructions [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/debugging-asp-net-core-2-source). The two important steps are to disable "Just My Code" and enable downloading symbols.

**Why it returns 200 with invalid JSON**

This is because of how it constructs the response. It does not buffer your query results into memory, and then send them. It sends the response headers first, *then* enumerates the results and sends them *as they come in*. You might call this "streaming" the results, since the results are not kept in memory.

This can be a good thing in cases where your results might be very large. There is no point loading the entire result set into memory just to send it off again.

But the downside is that if an error happens while enumerating the results, you can no longer change the response header (which includes the HTTP status code) because that has already arrived at the client. At the moment the exception happens, the response stream is closed without writing anything further. That causes the invalid JSON.

**Options**

You will have to balance the benefits of streaming the results with confusing errors. You have two options:

1. Catch the exception in a global exception handler so *you* know it happened, but you cannot change the 200 response to the client.
2. Force it to actually make the query inside of your method, using something like `ToList()` or `First()`, depending on what you want. That gives you the benefit of catching any exceptions *there*, and giving a more meaningful error message, but it does load all the results into memory first.

```
public IEnumerable Get() {
    try {
        return _db.AllThings.ToList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _logger.LogError(e, "There was an exception getting "AllThings");
        throw; //this will rethrow the exception, or you can return some other IQueryable
    }
}
```

**Is it a bug?**

The result isn't ideal, but it's hard to come up with a solution to it. This did actually come up before and the [conclusion](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5083#issuecomment-235631483) is telling, especially this part, commenting on the workarounds:

> Obviously both of these things require more server-side resources, which is why we don't have this kind of behavior by default.

The only way to change the response code on error is to buffer everything into memory *before* starting the response. But if they did that by default then that's arguably less intuitive - if you return an `IEnumerable` you should expect it to stream the response, since that's really the whole benefit of `IEnumerable` in general.

So... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks, yes I know it's short hand. Unfortunately it doesn't throw either way

Comment: Updated post to show that when executing the query synchronously I see an error, but when returning IQueryable I don't

Comment: Sadly I already have break on all exceptions turned on, it's throwing inside the EF Core code somewhere, but I can't find any options to have those exposed (though I've tried a few)

Comment: I was just able to replicate this, so I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, it may be that there is no "switch" to start logging these, and it needs some custom filter. But that would surprise me, trapping unexpected errors is crucial.  EDIT: I can see these exceptions happening if I added something to handle ALL exceptions, e.g. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException

Comment: That's probably your only real solution if you don't want to change your controller code. I updated my answer with my findings.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the only way the moment, just catch all first chances and log. Frustrating for a client as it simply returns invalid data (even if the db is unavailable). Thanks for creating an issue on git

Comment: So turns out that it was [brought up before](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5083). There isn't really a good solution for changing anything in ASP.NET Core itself. I updated my answer with the reasons why. It'll have to be something that you know and manage.